# Oracle 11g SQL select max integer value of varchar column

Tags: sql, oracle

#### myTable

```
UNID
 9
 10
```

UNID is a VARCHAR2

`select max(UNID) from myTable` returns the UNID with the highest lexicographic value (9).

how do i select the UNID with the highest integer value (10)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't

```
select max(to_number(UNID)) from yourTable
```

work?